# Remove Contact select option form file select options

Tags: java, android, android-intent, picking

I am opening file pick Intent with, Bellow code

```
Intent intent_upload = new Intent();
    intent_upload.setType("*/*");
    intent_upload.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent_upload, Constants.FILE_PICK_REQUEST_CODE);
```

I Want remove Contact option from list, please can anyone help.

Thanks[image]

Comment: You are asking for all types of content (`*/*`). Contacts are a type of content. If you do not want contacts, do not ask for `*/*` for a MIME type.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare for Quick replay, If I not ask for "*/*" it is not allowing me to select files available in google drive. Making those files disable for selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below code I think it can help you and also refers [Link](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

```
Intent intent_upload = new Intent();
        intent_upload.setType("*/*");
        intent_upload.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent_upload.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent_upload, Constants.FILE_PICK_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Thanks @hharry_tech helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what type of intent (apps) you want to open. Now you set offer me all apps:

```
intent_upload.setType("*/*");
```

This can be different type for images, music, documents etc. eg.:

```
intent.setType("image/*");
```

Comment: intent_upload.setType("image/*");
 String[] mimeTypes = {"audio/*", "video/*", "text/*", "application/*", "multipart/*", "message/*", "model/*"};

I am using this for all file types. But it is not allowing me to select files available in google Drive.

Comment: Eg. "text/*" offers Google Drive as an option. Is GDrive in that Genymotion emulator installed?

Comment: I am using my device,   but it is not allow ing to select files lilse, Like Image, pdf etc.

Comment: I'm afraid you must write your own logic that will recognise what files must be opened with which apps/intents.

Answer (score 0):

As CommonsWare said you don't have alternatives than setting the specific `MIME_TYPES` and ignore using `"*/*"`. Use specified `MIME_TYPES` like here..

```
    String[] mimetypes = {"image/*", "video/*"};
    Intent intent_upload = new Intent();
    intent_upload.setType("image/*,video/*");
    intent_upload.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
    intent_upload.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intent_upload, Constants.FILE_PICK_REQUEST_CODE);
```